# Laravel 5.5 - Use Auth in vendor packages

Tags: laravel, authentication

Is there a way to use Auth::check() or call Auth::user() in vendor packages ?

I tried to use :
- Middleware web,
- use Auth;

Both not working.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure. Your code is correct and works perfectly. But be sure to spesify 'use' block

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code:

```
Retrieving The Authenticated User
You may access the authenticated user via the Auth facade:

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

// Get the currently authenticated user...
$user = Auth::user();

// Get the currently authenticated user's ID...
$id = Auth::id();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but it doesn't work :-( So, I overwrite the package controller with custom controller in App\Http\Controller.